# Share multiple Uri to email/ whatsapp

Tags: android

My app is setup in the manifest as photo provider.
Now when in email app you select attach files and select my app i managed to share one image file but when attaching multiple photo Uri nothing happens.

any suggestions?

```
Intent mResultIntent = new Intent("my_custom_string.ACTION_RETURN_MULTIPLE");
mResultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
mResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mResultIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); // "image/jpeg"  getContentResolver().getType(uris.get(0))
//mResultIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
mResultIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
//mResultIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, c);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mResultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the right way of sharing single file uri and multiple uris when some app like google mail call your app for attach a file.

```
               if (uri != null) {
                    System.out.println("SINGLE");
                    Intent mResultIntent = new Intent("com.example.gallery.ACTION_RETURN_FILE");
                    mResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    mResultIntent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));

                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mResultIntent);
                    finish();
                }else{

                    ArrayList<Uri> uris = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                    System.out.println("MULTIPLE " + uris.get(0).toString());

                    Intent mResultIntent = new Intent();
                    mResultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    mResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    mResultIntent.setType(getContentResolver().getType(uris.get(0))); // "image/jpeg"  getContentResolver().getType(uris.get(0))

                    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "com.example.gallery", uris.get(0) );

                    if (uris.size() > 1){
                        for (int i = 1; i < uris.size(); i++){
                            clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(uris.get(i)) );
                        }
                    }

                    mResultIntent.setClipData(clipData);

                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mResultIntent);
                    finish();


                }
```

Comment: How can I send multiple images from my app to Whatsapp with the specifically selected contact?